# Is my understanding of thread model when consuming Aws Kinesis source with Flink correct?

Tags: java, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

Here are two references to Apache Flink documentation I'm reading:
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/datastream/kinesis/#kinesis-consumer
(Paragraph that starts with "Note that")

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/datastream/kinesis/#polling-default-record-publisher

Let's say I have a Kinesis stream with 10 shards that I am consuming into a Flink job.

My understanding of the first documentation: if my data source parallelism is set to 10 then each shard will be assigned to a slot and that slot will then process from that shard.  However if less than 10, 1 or more slots will be assigned multiple shards to process.  Is this right?

Then in the 2nd link, my understanding: for each slot there will be one thread to always be checking for new shards and then 1 thread to consume the shard it was assigned if it was only assigned one shard however if, because of lack of parallelism, this slot was assigned more than 1 shard then it will create a thread for each of the shards within this slot, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, your understandings are right. Actually `FlinkKinesisConsumer` can consume messages from multiple Kinesis streams. The main thread of kinesis consumer keeps discovering new shards, and for each shard assigned to current consumer(Flink source subtask), there will be a thread to pull data from that shard.

Comment: ok so just to confirm, each subtask gets an instance of FlinkKinesisConsumer.  If that subtask gets assigned multiple shards then FlinkKinesisConsumer will spin up a separate thread for each shard?  Also is there also a thread that discovers new shards per FlinkKinesisConsumer?  Meaning that if a FlinkKinesisConsumer is assigned 3 shards that means there are actual 4 threads total for that consumer?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation.  Is ever any advantage of specifying parallelism in the consumer less than number of kinesis shards?